How to use STM discovery board as an external debugger using SWD
I have F407G Disc1 board where it has the SWD ports and I want use this board as a standalone external debugger and I went through the manual for the connections but got stuck
Also found a thread in stack exchange where the connections are given as below


Where are the pins PA13 and PA14 here?
It would be really helpful if the name of the respective pins be given here

Did you read the manual section 6.1.5 how to use it to program and debug an external STM32? Where exactly you are stuck?

PA13 and PA14 are microcontroller pins. As suggested before, you should read the manual, or check connections in gerber files (avaliable at stmicroelectronics site). Don't forget to remove jumpers shown on picture to use discovery as external SWD debugger

The UM1472
Discovery kit with STM32F407VG MCU manual provided by ST Microelectronics has the pinout.

Pin 1 is indicated by the white dot on the CN2 connector.
If you intend to debug an external MCU (not the MCU on the same discovery board), then you have to find the MCU pins by referring to the target MCU datasheet. Say your target MCU is STM32F103C8 (LQFP48 package) then connect the pins on the CN2 connector to the pins of the target MCU as follows. The numbers (1-5) in red are the pin numbers on the CN2 connector.

And remember to remove the 2 jumpers on the CN3 connector.

If you change your mind and wish to debug the MCU on the same discovery board, then you have to put back those 2 jumpers. Also remember to disconnect the wires from the CN2 connectors to the external MCU (since you cannot debug 2 MCUs at the same time). CN3 jumpers are to select either external MCU (jumpers removed) or on-board MCU (jumpers attached).

Thank you for the clarification, the mistake was actually from my side I had interchanged the Data and Clock pins
